# Windows Updates - Download but not install

Tags: windows, windows-update, manual

I need to manually apply Windows updates on a few servers. The Actual Windows Update settings are disabled as they're managed by us (we also use SCCM for them, but the deployment is not 100% completed).
So my question is: Once I manually check **online** for updates and then I select the ones I want to install, is there a way to **just download** them and then let me click Install at a later stage?

For instance, I'd like to go start the download process around 11PM and then in the morning do the install (perhaps this server is in use during night). This will save me lots of time in the morning as the first run of downloads is done.

I couldn't really find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import [this PSWindowsUpdate](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) PowerShell module and use the function `Get-WUInstall` with the parameter `-DownloadOnly` to download all available Windows Update. It uses the source form the computer policy, unless specified otherwise (parameters `-WindowsUpdate` or `-MicrosoftUpdate`).

Comment: This is a great idea. Never thought of PS for this! Thanks.

Comment: What do I do after downloading updates with the powershell script? When I am ready to install the updates, do I issue another powershell command, or do I run Windows Update through the GUI and it will see the downloads and resume with the install, or perhaps something else?